# How to switch b/w git and mercurial subrepo in a mercurial repo

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

Currently I am using a mercurial repo that has multiple mercurial subrepos. I am migrating these subrepos to git and still keeping the mercurial repo pointing at these git subrepos (which is supported by mercurial, now). I want to know if it is possible at some point to update the mercurial repo to an old changeset to get the mercurial subrepos back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this is **The Natural Way (tm)** of handling subrepos in Mercurial:

Adding|having subrepo in main repo is (at versioned file level) is just two additional *versioned files* (`.hgsub` and `.hgsubstate`). When you changed subrepos, you changed these files in *some changeset*. If|when you update to changeset prior to git-subrepo migration, as part of Working Directory update you'll get old subrepos definition

Comment: but this way shouldn't the subrepos (that are now git) contain the .hg folder of the older mercurial subrepos as well? otherwise, when you revert to an old state in the main repo and it wants to go to a certain changeset in the old mercurial subrepo, it will not be able to find that changeset in the old subrepo (because there is no .hg folder anymore).

Comment: @mkmostafa - no-no!!! Read about subrepos internals - .hgsub and .hgsubstate define only "how to reach **external** repo, which is repository per se and which changeset from this repo to use in each main repo". Subrepo just have to be reachable (external or nested)

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. When I update the main repo, I get the following:  
`% hg update --config ui.merge=internal:merge --rev 99 --clean  
pulling subrepo from ssh://<remote link> 
Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. 
abort: git fetch error 128 `
When I update to an old changeset, the ".hgsub" reverted & loses the ssh link to git subrepo & it tries to do a fetch as shown. I dont know why it still thinks that the subrepo is git though the ".hgsub" is reverted apparently.